# Need guidance on a simple pig game that terminates and ends

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a simple Pig game.. The problem that i have is that the program terminates. 
For example, when i run it, entering two players and two names works perfectly, and so does the first round.. as soon as i enter n, and the turn goes to player 2, the program just stops.. I would like it to continue until the score is reached..

Below is my code.. I would appreciate ANY help.. I am totally lost on this one..
And yes... I am a beginner..

### Thank you!!

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Player> users = initialize();


        for (Player p : users) {
            System.out.println(p.getNick() + "'s turn!"); 
            System.out.println("Your score is: " + p.getScoreTotal() + "!");
            takeTurn(p);              
              if (p.getScoreTotal() >= 100) {
                System.out.println(p.getNick() + "wins! Congratulations"); 
                return;
              }
        } 

  }


  private static ArrayList<Player> initialize() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Pig!");
    System.out.println("How many will play the game?");

    int qusers = sc.nextInt();

    sc.nextLine();

    ArrayList<Player> users = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= qusers; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the name of player " + i + ":");
      users.add(new Player(sc.nextLine(), 1, 6));
    }
    return users;
  }

  private static void takeTurn(Player p) {
    String input = "";
    int currentScore = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
          p.rollDice();
          currentScore += p.getDieWorth();
          System.out.println(p.getNick() + "'s dice rolled " + p.getDieWorth());
          if (p.getDieWorth() != 1) {
            System.out.println("Your score is: " + currentScore + " for this round.");
            System.out.println("Do you want to roll again? (j/n)");
            input = sc.nextLine();
       } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            currentScore = 0;
        }
    } 
    while ((input.equals("j")) && (p.getDieWorth() != 1));
    p.increaseScore(currentScore);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you're already using eclipse, have you tried setting a breakpoint somewhere in your code so you can step through the execution one line at a time?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And clearly when `input` isn't "j" the loop ends.

Comment: @fpsColton Thank you for the welcome and the tip! 
I am new t eclipse and java, and didnt think about setting breakpoints in the code! I will take this with me in my future coding! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code.

```
    for (Player p : users) {
        System.out.println(p.getNick() + "'s turn!"); 
        System.out.println("Your score is: " + p.getScoreTotal() + "!");
        takeTurn(p);              
          if (p.getScoreTotal() >= 100) {
            System.out.println(p.getNick() + "wins! Congratulations"); 
            return;
          }
    }
```

This only goes through the users once. `for` goes through each user and then it's done. You need a while loop.

```
    //this is somewhat messy, but it gets the point across
    Player p = users.get(0);
    int playerIndex = users.size();
    while(p.getScoreTotal() < 100) {
        if(playerIndex == users.size()) {
            playerIndex = 0;
        }
        p = users.get(playerIndex);
        playerIndex++;
        System.out.println(p.getNick() + "'s turn!"); 
        System.out.println("Your score is: " + p.getScoreTotal() + "!");
        takeTurn(p);              
    } 
    System.out.println(p.getNick() + "wins! Congratulations"); 
    return;
```

Comment: Of course I needed a while loop! 
Thank you very much for your help.. Honestly I have been working this..I shouldhave seen before that the for loop was the wrong aproach.. Works like a charm now!